# summing rows of specific columns then dividing by the sum

Tags: r, function, sum, divide

I am simply trying to sum certain columns in a row and then divide the cells within the row by that sum. And I am wanting to do this in every row. for example, if we take the data set:

| lose | draw | win | goals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 2 | 5 | 12 |
| 1 | 2 | 13 | 21 |

We will ignore the goals scored and sum the win, lose and draw columns for the row, then by dividing each cell by the sum value we obtain:

| lose | draw | win | goals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7/14 | 2/14 | 5/14 | 12 |
| 1/16 | 2 /16 | 13/16 | 21 |

The code I have tried using is:

```
Df_new <-t(apply(Df, select = c(lose, draw, win), function(x) x/sum(x)))
```

However, I am getting the error:

**Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default**

which a google search says I am missing a margin. But I thought that I had specified this by electing the columns.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way to specify the column (by sub-setting `Df`), and then indicating the margin as `1`

```
Df_new = t(apply(Df[,c(1:3)], 1, \(x) x/sum(x)))

       lose      draw       win
[1,] 0.5000 0.1428571 0.3571429
[2,] 0.0625 0.1250000 0.8125000
```

Comment: use `function(x)` if `\(x)` does not work with your version of R

Comment: That's worked nicely, however it has gotten rid of my other columns completely.. Thank you

Comment: you could assign to `Df$new` instead of 'Df_new.'. i just followed your original post. or, you could rename and cbind